# access denied when trying to enter reqacc.aspx page

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am trying to enter http://portal/test/_layouts/reqacc.aspx?type=web
But I getting an error message: "Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource."
I am site collection administrator on the site.
Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Being a Site Collection Administrator does not matter. You need to enable Access Requests for the site.

To enable Access Requests manually, go to Site Actions > Site Settings > Users and Permissions > Site permissions, then click Manage Access Requests. Click the checkbox for Allow requests for access and set the email address.

To enable Access Requests programmatically, set the [SPWeb.RequestAccessEmail](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.requestaccessemail.aspx) property.